# SVG mask video inside path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mask

Trying to attempt to mask a video on top of a SVG path heart. However, keep failing as it doesnt want to mask on top of it.

Its on a react application but even on a codepen.io / jsfiddle it continuously fails.

The entire video should be submerged inside the heart itself but it just always lays on top of it.

**Here is my attempt**

```css
.example-video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.example-video video {
  width: 50%;
}
.example-video svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.example-video svg > path {
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<div class="example-video">
  <video autoPlay="autoplay" controls="true" playsInline mask="url(#mask)" muted loop preload="true" poster="http://i.imgur.com/xHO6DbC.png">
    <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" />
  </video>

  <svg version="1.1" id="p.svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 980.2914 884.5557" enableBackground="new 0 0 980.2914 884.5557" xmlSpace="preserve">
    <path opacity="0.05" fill="#E35D5D" d="M493.9887,130.1238L493.9887,130.1238C419.5373,4.797,257.8407-37.3296,131.6182,36.1312
                              C4.3062,110.2269-37.5245,274.4576,36.6059,401.6698l215.8423,370.3983c28.1165,48.2495,90.0233,64.5706,138.2729,36.4541
                              l368.4115-214.6845c127.2958-74.1791,172.7084-240.1479,98.7059-367.5465C783.976,99.1337,621.0024,56.1091,493.9887,130.1238z" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="3.1978" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M151.0414,716.6817L151.0414,716.6817
                              c-2.6854-4.5204-8.5175-6.0399-13.0702-3.3902c-4.592,2.6725-6.1008,8.5961-3.427,13.1844l7.7851,13.3598
                              c1.0141,1.7403,3.247,2.3289,4.9873,1.3148l13.2881-7.7433c4.5914-2.6756,6.2294-8.6618,3.5602-13.257
                              C161.5008,715.5639,155.6226,714.0121,151.0414,716.6817z" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="2.7402" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M186.6779,44.1803L186.6779,44.1803
                              c-1.4613-2.4599-4.635-3.2867-7.1125-1.8449c-2.4988,1.4543-3.3199,4.6778-1.8649,7.1747l4.2365,7.2701
                              c0.5519,0.947,1.767,1.2674,2.714,0.7155l7.2311-4.2138c2.4985-1.456,3.3899-4.7136,1.9374-7.2141
                              C192.3697,43.572,189.1709,42.7276,186.6779,44.1803z" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="2.5752" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M978.3951,400.8979
                              c-0.5042,0.934-0.5042,2.0591,0,2.993c0.3052,0.4453,0.5839,0.9083,0.835,1.3862c0.5513,1.3705-0.4096,2.8669-1.3862,3.9854
                              c-0.6144,0.7089-1.3075,1.6697-0.8979,2.5203c0.1919,0.3133,0.4371,0.5904,0.7246,0.8192c2.0887,2.0325,2.1343,5.3734,0.1018,7.4622
                              c-0.5895,0.6058-1.3159,1.0612-2.1182,1.3277" />
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <path fill="#ffffff" d="M528.4855,192.3897L528.4855,192.3897C454.034,67.0629,292.3375,24.9363,166.115,98.3971
                                    C38.8029,172.4928-3.0277,336.7236,71.1027,463.9358L286.945,834.3341c28.1165,48.2495,90.0233,64.5706,138.2729,36.4541
                                    l368.4115-214.6845c127.2958-74.1792,172.7084-240.1479,98.7059-367.5465C818.4728,161.3996,655.4992,118.375,528.4855,192.3897z" />
      </mask>
    </defs>

    <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="7" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M747.8805,524.349
                                 c108.1955-68.637,139.1927-213.677,70.5558-321.8725S606.4696,62.2462,498.2741,130.8832l0,0" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @MichaelMullany can you please elaborate on how i can potentially fix this. Ive tried moving to #mask as well but still no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inlined css `mask-image` might be a more convenient approach, since mask-images allow better responsive scaling of the mask elements.

#### Example: mask-image

```css
video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

.example-video {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.svgBG {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
}

.masked {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1600 900'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23000' transform='translate(375 25) scale(1.8)' d='M 264 96 L 264 96 C 227 34 146 12 83 49 C 19 86 -2 168 36 232 L 143 417 c 14 24 45 32 69 18 l 184 -107 c 64 -37 86 -120 49 -184 C 409 81 328 59 264 96 z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1600 900'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23000' transform='translate(375 25) scale(1.8)' d='M 264 96 L 264 96 C 227 34 146 12 83 49 C 19 86 -2 168 36 232 L 143 417 c 14 24 45 32 69 18 l 184 -107 c 64 -37 86 -120 49 -184 C 409 81 328 59 264 96 z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
  mask-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-video">
  <svg class="svgBG" id="p.svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 980.2914 884.5557">
  <path opacity="0.05" fill="#E35D5D" d="M493.9887,130.1238L493.9887,130.1238C419.5373,4.797,257.8407-37.3296,131.6182,36.1312 C4.3062,110.2269-37.5245,274.4576,36.6059,401.6698l215.8423,370.3983c28.1165,48.2495,90.0233,64.5706,138.2729,36.4541 l368.4115-214.6845c127.2958-74.1791,172.7084-240.1479,98.7059-367.5465C783.976,99.1337,621.0024,56.1091,493.9887,130.1238z" />
  <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="3.1978" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M151.0414,716.6817L151.0414,716.6817c-2.6854-4.5204-8.5175-6.0399-13.0702-3.3902c-4.592,2.6725-6.1008,8.5961-3.427,13.1844l7.7851,13.3598c1.0141,1.7403,3.247,2.3289,4.9873,1.3148l13.2881-7.7433c4.5914-2.6756,6.2294-8.6618,3.5602-13.257C161.5008,715.5639,155.6226,714.0121,151.0414,716.6817z" />
  <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="2.7402" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M186.6779,44.1803L186.6779,44.1803c-1.4613-2.4599-4.635-3.2867-7.1125-1.8449c-2.4988,1.4543-3.3199,4.6778-1.8649,7.1747l4.2365,7.2701c0.5519,0.947,1.767,1.2674,2.714,0.7155l7.2311-4.2138c2.4985-1.456,3.3899-4.7136,1.9374-7.2141C192.3697,43.572,189.1709,42.7276,186.6779,44.1803z" />
  <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="2.5752" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M978.3951,400.8979
c-0.5042,0.934-0.5042,2.0591,0,2.993c0.3052,0.4453,0.5839,0.9083,0.835,1.3862c0.5513,1.3705-0.4096,2.8669-1.3862,3.9854c-0.6144,0.7089-1.3075,1.6697-0.8979,2.5203c0.1919,0.3133,0.4371,0.5904,0.7246,0.8192c2.0887,2.0325,2.1343,5.3734,0.1018,7.4622c-0.5895,0.6058-1.3159,1.0612-2.1182,1.3277" />
  <g>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#E35D5D" strokeWidth="7" strokeLinecap="round" strokeMiterlimit="10" d="M747.8805,524.349 c108.1955-68.637,139.1927-213.677,70.5558-321.8725S606.4696,62.2462,498.2741,130.8832l0,0" />
  </g>
</svg>


  <video class="masked" autoPlay="autoplay" controls="true" muted loop preload="true" poster="http://i.imgur.com/xHO6DbC.png">
    <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" />
  </video>
</div>

<p>Mask svg (before inlining)</p>
<svg width="160" height="90" style="border:1px solid #ccc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 900">
<path fill="#000" transform="translate(450 100) scale(1.5)" d="M 264 96 L 264 96 C 227 34 146 12 83 49 C 19 86 -2 168 36 232 L 143 417 c 14 24 45 32 69 18 l 184 -107 c 64 -37 86 -120 49 -184 C 409 81 328 59 264 96 z" />
</svg>
```

You can use [Yoksel's svg](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder) URL-encoder for this task.

Your background artwork could also be used as a static `<img>` or `background-image` like so:

```
<img src="heart-bg.svg">

.example-video {
  background-image:url(heart-bg.svg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to get SVG masks to work on the video element - so you might want to try something a bit simpler like the below. (You'd have to go back and redo your heart shape so it fits the aspect ratio of the video element).

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 52%;
  height: 32%;
}
```

```html
  <video autoPlay="autoplay" controls="true" playsInline muted loop preload="true" poster="http://i.imgur.com/xHO6DbC.png">
    <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" />
  </video>

  <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 980 950" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <defs>
    <mask id="myMask">
      <rect fill="white" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"/>
 <path fill="black" d="M528.4855,192.3897L528.4855,192.3897C454.034,67.0629,292.3375,24.9363,166.115,98.3971
                                    C38.8029,172.4928-3.0277,336.7236,71.1027,463.9358L286.945,834.3341c28.1165,48.2495,90.0233,64.5706,138.2729,36.4541
                                    l368.4115-214.6845c127.2958-74.1792,172.7084-240.1479,98.7059-367.5465C818.4728,161.3996,655.4992,118.375,528.4855,192.3897z" />
    </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" mask="url(#myMask)" stroke="white"/> 
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) or [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask). It is not completely clear to me why your mask does not work, but try to clean up the code.

```css
video {
  /*clip-path: url(#clip);*/
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<div class="example-video">
  <video autoPlay="autoplay" controls="true" muted loop preload="true" poster="http://i.imgur.com/xHO6DbC.png">
    <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" />
  </video>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <path transform="translate(130) scale(.8)" d="M 264 96 L 264 96 C 227 34 146 12 83 49 C 19 86 -2 168 36 232 L 143 417 c 14 24 45 32 69 18 l 184 -107 c 64 -37 86 -120 49 -184 C 409 81 328 59 264 96 z" />
      </clipPath>
      <mask id="mask">
        <path fill="white" transform="translate(130) scale(.8)" d="M 264 96 L 264 96 C 227 34 146 12 83 49 C 19 86 -2 168 36 232 L 143 417 c 14 24 45 32 69 18 l 184 -107 c 64 -37 86 -120 49 -184 C 409 81 328 59 264 96 z" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```